# How travelling portals finds best routes from A to B?

Tags: database, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am really stuck on this, days are gone and I still can't even imagine, how it can be possible.

I am sure you know some travelling portals. You set source and destination and it prints possible trains/buses/flights you can use. This in itself is so easy. Absolutely no problem with any database system.

Problem comes when there is not only direct paths. How they search paths with changes? How they can find best ways from a lot of possible ways with only minimal delay? Do they use some special databases?

Comment: Pick a random route(inefficient or good doesnt matter), then pick another random route with big variance. Select the better one(less money/less time). Decrease variance. Select another random, select the better one. Decrease variance. Select. Random. Decrease. Select ... until the error satisfies a boundary(e.g. short path). If stuck in a dead-end, increase variance, stuck--->increase variance again. Then try again.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory, and Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Dikstra finds only one best way or not? I can do that, but I need to find not one, but `n` best ways.

Comment: If you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Related_problems_and_algorithms you'll see how Dijkstra's algorithm combined with edge removal will let you find the shortest possible paths.  Once found you can rank them.  Note that there is a combinatorial explosion of work to be done, finding the shortest 10 is generally a lot more work than the shortest 5.